# How to increase the amount of lines shown by Docker BuildKit?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

When building a Docker image with BuildKit enabled, it only shows the last 6 lines the build log at the same time. `--progress=plain` shows all the thousands of lines at once but I would like to get something in between, let's say 20. Is it possible to change the default value of 6 lines to some custom value below infinity?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can set a default value to monitor the progress, but if you try using Linux by piping the output to sort something like : docker build --progress=plain . 2>&1 >/dev/null | sort --version-sort